# ApplySimple Formula for Current year in Microstrategy

Tags: oracle, analytics, microstrategy

I'd like to nkow how to extract the current year using an ApplySimple formula for an Oracle DB being used on microstrategy.

The formula I tried is :

ApplySimple("to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP,'Year')")

Even though this formula is a valid one - when I try using this formula to create an attribute , and display it in a report , I get no results( blank column )

What I'm essentially trying to do is compare this current year attribute to another year attribute and create  afilter based on this.

Any help wll be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with `ApplySimple` at all, it can be done directly in a filter.

Qualify on the attribute form that you want to compare (presumably the Year ID), and then in the Operator section, change the dropdown from its default 'Value' to 'Custom'.

This allows you to use MicroStrategy's built-in functions in your qualification. The current year can be returned by putting:

```
Year(CurrentDate())
```

for your comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to compare the string "twenty fourteen"? Because, `TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'year')` would return that. Instead, you might need the `YYYY` format :

`TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'YYYY')`

But that is still a string.

You probably need `NUMBER` :

So, I would prefer, `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSTIMESTAMP)` Because, this will return `2014` as `NUMBER`.

```
SQL> SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSTIMESTAMP) FROM DUAL;

EXTRACT(YEARFROMSYSTIMESTAMP)
-----------------------------
                         2014
```

**Formula**

If the attribute is `NUMBER` data type, you might need this formula :

```
ApplySimple("EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSTIMESTAMP)")
```

Comment: I'm still getting a blank result. I tried changing the Form format->Type to number (of the created attribute) to no avail.

Comment: Just use `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSTIMESTAMP` as I suggested.

Comment: Could you please modify the answer to indicate the full ApplySimple formula that is to be used ? 
Thanks

Comment: What is the data type of the other attribute you are comparing to?

Comment: @Anant, see formula in my answer.

Comment: As of now I'm not comparing it to any other attribute. it is a static attribute that I'm trying to create. 
I tried the code in the Addtional Informatino provided by you. However , I still get a blank column

Comment: @Anant, please see this http://community.microstrategy.com/t5/Object-Development/Column-Alias-tab-is-blank-when-using-an-applysimple-expression/td-p/141260

Comment: @Anant, Let me know if the link information works for you, I will add the steps in the answer.

Comment: I Tried the suggestions in the link - I still get a blank column

Comment: Also - the link isn't really relevant since I'm creating a static attribute. It has a constant value. Is that one fo the reasons why I'm getting a blank column ?

Comment: all examples i have seen they use #0 which is kind of bind variable instead of directly using SYSTIMESTAMP